# TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Sorry guys, I couldn't find the satisfying answer to print part of json response. Can someone help me here please:

```
import json
import requests
import pprint 

response = requests.get('<api endpoing>')
json_data = response.json()
print(json.dumps(json_data, indent=4, sort_keys=True))
```

Json response would be

```
{
    "Value1": "SomeValue",
    "data": {
        "subval1": false,
        "subval2": "0a4",
        "subval3": "",
        "subval4": "Click h!",
        "subval5": "1002",
        "subval6": "932",
        "subval7": "i2",
        "subval8": 250,
        "subval9": 0,
        "subval10": 1,
        "subval11": 3,
        "subval12": 1,
        "subval13": "<!>",
        "subval14": "",
        "subval15": "Click !!",
        "subval16": "",
        "subval17": 300
    },
    "error": true,
    "message": "Success",
    "status": 200
}
```

Now, I would like to traverse and print only the "data": values. I will do the following

```
data = json.loads(json_data)
data_set = (data['data'])
print(data_set)
```

But the error Im getting: TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'

Comment: check the type of `json_data`. If it's already a dict then don't json decode...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You don't need to `json.loads(json_data)` as it is already a python dict, you just need to output this dict directly. And outputing json string from a dict is `json.dumps()`'s job :

```
json.dumps(json_data["data"])
```

Comment: ah! Thanks guys! I should have checked the type. Learning days.

Answer (score 3):

Actually `json()` method returns a **json** object,so you don't need to use `json.loads`

Or you can use

```
r=requests.get("")
print json.loads(r.content)
```

See more details from [JSON Response Content](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#json-response-content).