# Convert to JSON without index values using pandas column orient

Tags: python, json, pandas

Is it possible to write json to file without index values and nesting using any Python library function e.g. pandas.DataFrame.to_json? My dataframe is only ever going to have one row, and the system that parses it cannot handle index values and requires the structure to be in this specific way.

What I want to achieve:

```python
{"A":"D","B":"F","C":"G"}
```

Code example:

```python
import pandas as pd
data = [["D", "F", "G"]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["A", "B", "C"])
result = df.to_json(orient="columns")

with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

Tried so far:

```python
df.to_json(orient="columns")
# {"A":{"0":"D"},"B":{"0":"F"},"C":{"0":"G"}}

df.to_json(orient="records")
# [{"A":"D","B":"F","C":"G"}]

df.to_json(orient="split")
# {"columns":["A","B","C"],"index":[0],"data":[["D","F","G"]]}
```

While what I want looks suspiciously like Python dictionary, I still want to know how to write to the file, and writing a dictionary {"A":"D","B":"F","C":"G"} to file throws

```python
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not dict
```

Comment: call `str()` on it, or use `.to_json()` instead of `.to_dict()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: the JSON object must be str, not 'dict'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899389/typeerror-the-json-object-must-be-str-not-dict)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, since you only have one row:

```
>>> df.iloc[0].to_json()
'{"A":"D","B":"F","C":"G"}'
```

To write to file:

```
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(df.iloc[0].to_json())
```